# Wizards of the Coast Web Expansions

Tags: dnd-3.5e, wizards-of-the-coast

Is there a complete mirror of all the WotC expansions. It seems a lot of them are gone completely: not on the website, not on the Internet Archive, not on any mirrors. I can't find a lot of the stuff mentioned at the Guide to Free DnD. Namely any of the stuff on the ww2.wizards.com.

Comment: For reference, since you’re new here: if for some reason I’m wrong, and your question is different and not answered by the linked question’s answers, feel free to explain the differences by editing your question, and we can re-open it.